# How to set up Android Icons in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter

I am trying to set up icons for Android in Flutter.

I want an icon to show in the launch screen (when the app is starting) and a different icon to show on the home screen in Android.

First I have configured this using `launch_screen.xml` and `drawable` folders.
`launch_screen.xml` in `res\layout` folder I configured like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:src="@drawable/launch_screen" android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I have then placed `launch_screen.png` icon in drawable folders.

This worked perfectly until I changed the minimum supported version of Android from 28 to 29. I have not changed target version from 31. After this the behavior has changed and Android (or Flutter?) started using icons from mipmap folders which look really ugly in the launch screen.

I tried to modify `ic_launcher.xml` and `ic_launcher_round.xml` files in `mipmap-anydpi-v26` folder, and that did something, but not quite what I wanted.

This changed both the icon in the app folder in Android as well as the launch screen. What's worse when the phone is using round icons, the launch screen is also displaying a round icon (or rather it crops the square image to a round shape)!

How can I specify the icon I want for the launch screen without affecting the home page icons?

I do not want to use the splash screen as it requires me to specify how long I want it to show which I obviously cannot know in advance for every phone in the world. I just want something to show up when the app is starting so that user on a slow phone knows that it is happening and his phone has not just crashed.

Answer (score 0):

seek an image on your computer name it ic_logo_scree then past it in the drawer folder with ctrl+v

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:src="@drawable/ic_logo_scree" android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

i thing it a name conflit